# Why the sequence $\frac{2+a_n}{\sqrt{2+a_n^2}}$ is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given $\left\{ a_{n}\::\:n=1,\:2,\:3,\:\cdots\right\} $ is an infinite
sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, and every term is positive. How to prove
that the set

\begin{equation}
\left\{ \frac{2+a_{n}}{\sqrt{2+a_{n}^{2}}}\::\:n=1,\:2,\:3,\:\cdots\right\} 
\end{equation}
has a limit point?

Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem says that every bounded
infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a limit point. But how to prove
it is bounded? I tried this
\begin{equation}
\left|\frac{2+a_{n}}{\sqrt{2+a_{n}^{2}}}\right|\leq\left|\frac{2+a_{n}}{\sqrt{a_{n}^{2}}}\right|=\left|\frac{2+a_{n}}{a_{n}}\right|
\end{equation}
but does not seem work.

Or these is another way to show it has a limit point, without using Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Comment: Try to show that $$2+a_n\leqslant2\sqrt{2+a_n^2}$$

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}\frac{2+x}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}=\pm 1$$ and $\frac{2+x}{\sqrt{2+x^2}}$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$, hence it is necessarily bounded.

Comment: Why is that?  I know if E is a compact set, then f(E) is bounded.

Comment: @Lithium: such limits imply that for some $M$, $\left|f(x)\right|\leq \frac{3}{2}$ for any $|x|>M$. So you may apply your lemma to the interval $[-M,M]$.

Comment: ah yes, very smart approach. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can let intuition guide you: When $a_n$ is very small, it is negligible compared to $2$, so the fraction is close to $\sqrt{2}$. Similarly, when $a_n$ is very large, the fraction is very close to $a_n/\sqrt{a_n^2}=1$. In between these extremes, it is continuous, hence bounded. You could build that into a formal proof, but that is clearly overkill! But this quick reasoning gives you the answer very easily, it is *for sure* bounded.

Instead, note that you need to prove the existence of some $M$ so that $$ 2+a_n \le M\sqrt{2+a_n^2} .$$
Now square that inequality (note that both sides are positive), rearrange it a bit, say by collecting equal powers of $a_n$, and try find some value of $M$ that lets you prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Alt. hint:   let $a = \sqrt{2} \tan t$, then:

$$
\frac{2+a}{\sqrt{2+a^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2} + \tan t}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2 t}} = (\sqrt{2}+\tan t) \cdot |\cos t| \;\le\; \sqrt{2}|\cos t| + |\sin t|
$$